# Outlook Attachments Opening Slow over VPN

Tags: vpn, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

We have Outlook set up so that it can only be accessed when connected to our VPN when outside of our LAN. Recently, I have had 4 separate users complain about how slow attachments are opening when connected via VPN. I have tried emptying the Outlook temp file location on their computers. It seemed to help a little, but nothing significant. Has anyone ever heard of this happening before? Any recommended solutions?

Relevant information:

-Using a Watchguard VPN

-Everyone is using Outlook 2010

-Exchange 2010 SP2

-Everyone is using Cached Exchange Mode, no one is running directly off of Exchange.

-We have around 150 other people using the VPN on a regular basis and no one else is complaining about this happening. Just 4 people. The 4 people this is happening to started complaining about it within a week of each other.

-Google is returning nothing on this matter.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Do you know what kind of network they are connecting into the VPN from? Could be a bottle neck on their end.

Comment: I don't think it is a bottleneck on their end. Most of the time it is from a home network connection. Also, because cached exchange mode is on, it shouldn't be needed to grab these files over the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cached mode is really enabled & running.
Try to delete the `.ost` file and recreate it.

Comment: Why the downvote? If the attachment would have been available in the cache, it would not need to fetch it trough VPN! Thats very legitimate

Comment: I said in my question that Cached Exchange Mode is on (but I didn't give you the down vote).

Comment: But OST files can get corrupted, and because it oviously grabs the attachment from the network, something with your cached mode seems to be wrong on those clients ;)
Have you tried deleting the OST?